# Visual Basic application stops running after the computer goes to sleep

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm would like at some point to put a check box in Visual Basic 2015 that will auto start the program when the computer boots up, but i can not find the coding to do so. I have found a temporary fix by placing a copy of the program into the run folder. The problem is after the program starts and is running, if the user puts the computer into sleep/hibernate the program stops running.

Is there a way to resume running the program after waking up the computer from sleep/hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a task for the Task Scheduler to be performed at "On Connection to User Session"...or "At Startup"...or "On Workstation Unlock"...depending on the exact event you are looking for.

Have the Task launch your program.

Comment: I like the idea of it relaunches the program when the user logs in.

Comment: @Gloddox If this worked for you, can you mark it as the answer (click the check mark to the left of the answer) so anyone searching in the future will see that this question was resolved?  Thanks.